# Revoking bishoprics without opinion penalty

Tags: crusader-kings-2

If I wanted to revoke a feudal title, I would usually go via: have spymaster discover a plot / have the vassal rebel -> imprison the guy -> revoke his feudal title (e.g. county). This way I don't get any opinion penalty from my other vassals.
This does not seem to work with religious (at least Catholic) titles. When I uncover plot by some bishop, imprison him and try to revoke his bishopric - this sill incurs opinion penalty.
Why is this so and how do I nationalize the damn church holdings?

Related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228506/how-to-revoke-a-barony-title-in-ones-demesne-without-tyranny), but I'm specifically interested in Bishoprics, Prince-Bishoprics, etc.

Comment: Changing your own religion is out of the question? Cuz that's one way to do it, have a different religion by either converting yourself or him

Comment: When you have free investiture you could appoint the successor you want and then murder the bishop (or when you can imprison him, you can keep your hands clean by putting him in your oubliette until he dies). That won't get *you* the title, but usually you don't want to hold on to it anyway because you get a penalty for holding religious titles.

Comment: @phillipp, I'm looking to change prince- bishoprics to counties and the only way is to revoke. Otherwise the inheritee keeps the same titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In order to revoke without tyranny, imprisonment is NOT sufficient**. This applies to religious vassals as well as feudal vassals.  There's 3 ways to [revoke](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Title_revocation) without tyranny:

### 1. Have a claim on the title

There's various ways to do this , but the most straightforward is using your chancellor to fabricate a claim.
*note: your chancellor cannot fabricate on a barony-level title, e.g. a bishopric*

### 2. Target ruler is your direct vassal and is a traitor

This can be caused by the target rebelling and losing (or white peace?), or by the target refusing your request to stop backing a plot.
*note: barony-level titles(e.g. bishoprics) will never rebel*

### 3. Target ruler is of a different religion (and your realm laws allow it)

Depending on if you have the Conclave DLC and what realm laws you have passed, you may be able to revoke from vassals of a different religion. If you are able to obtain the title above your target and give it to a courtier of a different religion, that heathen (or infidel) will replace his vassals (including your target) with rulers of his religion . Once he's done, you can revoke your previously appointed title, and that (prince-)bishopric is now your direct vassal and ruled by a heathen! (or infidel!) From there you can revoke without upsetting any of your proper, god-fearing vassals.
*note: Religious revocation does not allow Christians to revoke from non-heretical Christians. e.g. a Catholic can revoke from a Cathar or Muslim, but not an Orthodox

note2: If granted title does not allow religious revocation, you have to wait for your pet heathen to convert his vassals*

Comment: I've read that prince-bishoprics are less likely to rebel. I would add this as a note to way 2, but I haven't confirmed it, yet.

Comment: 1. if bishopric is the capital of the county, will I get the claim on the bishopric-county, or the barony-county? 2. how can i increase likelihood of traitorship-event? If they love me to death and don't want to rebell?

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta You'll get a claim on the bishopric-county (a prince-bishopric). Check [Dacio's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/228722/6914) to your linked question for some ways to instigate rebellion. If you're talking about the in-game traitor accusation event, see [My other answer about the spy on action](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295255/6914), but make sure the target is not illegitimate, not a heratic/infidel, doesn't have a deviant trait/modifier, and hope you get the 10% chance of traitor rather than slanderer.

Answer (score 2):

This method might be a bit extreme, but if you *really* want this bishophoric:

1. Change your religion. The easiest way to do that as a catholic is by having your chaplain do cultural research in your capital. After a while he will suggest you to switch to a heresy.
2. Grant independence to the Bishop (or his liege, if there is a count or duke between you and him)
3. Immediately declare holy war

When you win a holy war, all titles in the conquered area which are not held by people of your religion go directly to you. Afterwards you can abandon your heresy to get rid of the opinion penalty with other catholics.

Just be careful: Remember that everyone in the area can join a holy war to back up the side which is of their religion. This means holy wars can escalate quickly.

Comment: The grant independence->declare war strategy can be used with other CBs. If the target holds >1 county, a de jure war can take a county. If the target holds a barony-lvl and you control the county, a de jure war can take all their barony-lvl titles in that county. Claim war if you have a claim. Sanctioned Invasion if you have a claim. If you go Muslim, county conquest will take the county if target has >1 county. If you go Pagan, county conquest and tribal invasion can take a county.